# unable to break two URLs joint through ~ using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I Am trying to break two URL's those are joint through `~` using .htaccess because these types of URLs making 404 error and our site ranking is affecting.
URL example is

```
/media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/200x/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/a/c/ac0023f.jpg~/media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/200x/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/a/c/ac0023f.jpg
```

and the rule that I am trying is:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)~(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

but I don't have any success right now.
So Can anybody help me to short out this problem? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you getting those two combined urls into one, if then you'll strip the second out?

Comment: yes i want strip out second one.

Comment: What i asked is WHY you're receiving a second url if it's not used altogether? can you prevent it from being sent?

Comment: No, I dont know from where these URL's are making. I just want to strip second URL or if we found "~" in URL then it redirects to home page.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^([^~]+)~.+$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But no luck.